# A conditional probability inequality

Tags: probability

How to prove the following inequality? $$|P(A)-P(A\mid B)|\le 1-P(B)$$
I know if $P(A)-P(A\mid B)\ge 0$, then $P(A)-P(A\mid B)\le P(A)-P(A\cap B)\le 1-P(B).$
But how to prove the other case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $P(A) = P(A \mid B) P(B) +P(A \mid B^C) \left( 1 - P(B) \right)$. So we find
$$ \left| P(A) - P(A \mid B) \right| = \left|   P(A \mid B)  - P(A \mid B^C)\right| \left( 1 -P(B)  \right) .$$
So all that you have to do, we can assume w.l.o.g. that $P(A \mid B) >P(A \mid B^C)$, is show 
\begin{align}
P(A \mid B)  - P(A \mid B^C)  \le 1,
\end{align}
Which holds true. So we have
$$\left| P(A) - P(A \mid B) \right| \le 1 - P(B).$$